# DispatcherPriority in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any documentation as to the exact meanings of each of the [DispatcherPriority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration values, in relation to a WPF application.

In particular, is there any practical difference between `Background` / `ContextIdle` / `ApplicationIdle` ? I've found myself using each of these in various parts of my code and would like to standardise on one value.

A typical usage would be in a data bound TreeView control. When setting an item 
 as selected (in the ViewModel), I want to first expand all of its parent items (again in the ViewModel), then wait for them to be fully rendered (in the View) before actually setting the selected property.

Comment: Good question but 'just pick one' might be a sufficient answer.

Comment: I believe that application idle may be delayed a little from the other two. I would pick the highest priority class that does what you need, in any case, and also consider whether you really need to be dispatching this way at all - since it can cause application instability if you aren't careful.

Comment: Which would be `Background` and would also probably best represent what you want to do, i.e. run something "in the background". That said, *my* code looked better after removing any occurance of DispatcherPriority.

Comment: You may take a look at the [WPF Threading Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model). Its not complete but I think its a good start.

Comment: My experience is that I like to wait for all wpf rendering is done before fetching some information from the rendered view. E.g. if you want to access an object from the view (a Usercontrol) and want to access it directly from codebehind for any reason, use "ContextIdle" priority.

Comment: I haven't been able to find exact definitions, so the best place to see exactly what they do will probably be the reference source for the [Dispatcher](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,078d6b27d9837a35).  It's a little ...verbose... though, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to understand how it is actually working is to see source code of it.

> .Net Framework source code is available at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

You can get answers for your question after checking out and understanding this code
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,ad208569500b2a1d

My quick understanding: there is a lot of priorities is just to give oportunity to specify priority of operation more precise if it will be needed by your code. There is no hidden events/states to perform operations of specific priorities. Alghoritm will take task with top priority and invoke it, and so on.